# Html table to excel export script showing error " missing close quote"

Tags: javascript, excel, export

I have html table and as per requirement I need to export into excel format so I am following some link and I integrated code according to the instructions but when I click on export button it is showing error

Error : missing close quote

link followed

https://www.blogdesire.com/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-using-javascript/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>
<script>
  function enable_btn(){
            var ts = String(new Date().getTime()), i = 0, out = '';
            for (i = 0; i < ts.length; i += 2) {
                out += Number(ts.substr(i, 2)).toString(36);
            }
            var newdate= ('d' + out);
            $(".place_btn").html('<button onclick="tableToExcel("testTable", '+newdate+')">Export</button>');
       }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the data for which it is showing this error

Comment: @aRvi Yes I will add few more code